# Migrating a .NET Framework 4.6 MVC project to .NET6

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, upgrade, .net-framework-version

I've installed the .NET Upgrade Assistant in my Visual Studio 2022 and tried to convert an existing .NET Framework 4.6 MVC project to .NET6. It didn't let me do a direct migration but instead offered to either use an existing project (and suggested one other project in the solution which already exists and is not empty) or creating a new project. I chose the new project version and I thought it would contain all the code from my MVC project but now targeting .NET6. What it created instead is an empty .NET6 project and the Upgrade Assistant output pane only says that this new project is somehow "linked" to the old one and the only "link" I see between them is that the tool added one new node inside the old project's `.csproj` file:

```
<_MigrateToProjectGuid>347acadf-d15a-442a-80a7-g5gg9872f8ab</_MigrateToProjectGuid>
```

inside the  node.

The new project doesn't seem to know about the old project at all.

What am I doing wrong in this upgrade?